# Regularization in Bayesian updating

Tags: bayesian, regularization

I'm building an online algorithm (I have streaming data) that does Bayesian Linear Regression.

Each time data comes in, I use standard Bayesian updating formulae to calculate the posterior, which then becomes the prior for the next batch of data. (For example, I use the formulae from Bishop's textbook below)

[image: Bayesian updating formulae from Bishop's (2006) textbook]

I then predict which treatment gives the highest expected outcome value, and then assign that treatment.

All's fine for models with few variables, but as dimensionality increases, I might want to do regularization. How should I do this?

Comment: Having a prior is already a form of regularization

Comment: Hmm. Do you mean having a prior is a form of regularization in that all coefficients "biased" towards the prior?

Comment: [This link](http://www.mit.edu/~9.520/spring09/Classes/class15-bayes.pdf) expands on @shimao's point.